# Не работает scroll на append

Tags: jquery

Не работает scroll на вставленные элементы, например:

```
$('.elem').scroll(function(){
  console.log('scroll')
})
```

а вот-так не работает:

```
$('body').append('<div class="elem"></div>')
$('.elem').scroll(function(){
  console.log('scroll')
})
```

Comment: Попробуй поместить append внутрь функции скролла

Comment: то есть вы имеете в виду <div class="elem"></div> оставить и в него подгружать?

Comment: если да, то другого способа нет?)

Comment: модно пример кода работающего и с проблемой. тут есть варианты касательно того, какой именно scroll event вы ловите.

Comment: Извиняюсь, вопрос был не правильно поставлен. После нажатие кнопки, вставляется элемент. И событие scroll не работает, но элемент прокручивается

Comment: $('.button').on('click', function(){
  $('body').append('<div class="elem">Здесь много элементов</div>')
})
$('.elem').on('scroll', function(){
  console.log($(this).scrollTop())
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) вместо scroll()

Если div подгружается динамически, по событию из вне (как нажатие кнопки или ajax запрос, то и событие скролл вы должны декларировать - там).

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.button').on('click', function(){ 

        $('body').append('<div class="elem">Scroll me<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>');     
        
        $('.elem').on('scroll', function() {
           console.log('Hallelujah');
        }); 
      
    })
});
```

```css
.elem {overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden; height:100px; color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<button class="button"> Click me </button>
</body>
```

Все работает

Comment: у меня в коде везде используется on('click')

Comment: вы уверены что вам нужен скол именно этого элемента, а не всей страницы?

Comment: да. Т.к. после нажатие кнопки, вставляется этот элемент. И событие scroll не работает, но элемент прокручивается

Comment: изменил ответ с примером, все работает. Либо выкладывайте более подробный код, либо мы будем и дальше ходить вокруг да около :)

Comment: так работает. А вы попробуйте так: <button class="button"></button><script>
$('.button').on('click', function(){
  $('body').append('<div class="elem">Здесь много элементов</div>')
})</script>

Comment: ну вот с куском кода все понятно - сейчас отредактирую ответ. Готово, удачи!

Comment: думаю вы получили ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: Работает, спасибо). Только есть проблема. Как заставить это работать, если элемент уже подгрузился? Вставить этот же код за функцию и в функцию?